# 1N4728A Zener diode not giving the expected voltage

Tags: voltage, zener

I've been trying to understand the proper usage of Zener diodes, but I've not been able to get the behaviour I expect based on my understanding.

For example, in the test circuit below I would expect the voltage across the Zener to be approximately 3.3 V (the datasheet indicates the [1N4728A](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/1N4728A_SER.pdf) has a Zener voltage of 3.3 V at a test current of 76 mA), yet I measure it as 4.05 V.  I've tried multiple replacement diodes to try to rule out a faulty part, but I get a similar result for each, so clearly there's something faulty in my understanding. Can someone explain the behaviour I'm seeing?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwihVF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For reference, here are photos of the diode in question, and the kit it came in:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to reduce current, datasheet specifications shows voltage tolerance and test current, at which you should get expected voltage with tolerance band. Zener diodes have differential resistance (slope of characteristic).

Comment: Marking error? With 4.05 V, current into 22 Ohm is only 43 mA.

Comment: How are you determining the actual current?

Comment: I believe the 1N4728A is supposed to have a voltage tolerance of 5% at the test current if I've understood correctly (so anywhere between 3.135v & 3.465v would be acceptable).
I'm calculating current based on the voltage across the resistor divided by its resistance, which in the above example will indeed give 43mA.  If the voltage across the diode were 3.3v as expected though, the current would be 77mA which is almost exactly the test current quoted by the datasheet.
I've tried using a 10 Ohm resistor to increase the current closer to 76mA, this gave 4.17v across the diode and 83mA current.

Comment: I may have figured out what's going on here.  The datasheet specifies a Zener resistance of 10 Ohms at the test current, which almost precisely accounts for the excess Zener voltage in the 83mA case.
I guess this was counter-intuitive to me because I assumed the quoted voltage at the test current would include the effect of the Zener resistance, but apparently not.

Comment: Also, the CircuitLab simulation for the above circuit seems to make the same error as myself and doesn't account for the Zener resistance correctly.

Comment: The actual voltage across the zener diode should be the rated voltage +/- the rated tolerance at the Iz test current. The dynamic resistance only comes into play when the current is different from test current. Either your resistor is something like 2.2Ω (in which case the diode would be getting very hot indeed), your meter is wonky (dying battery?- measuring the 5V on the same range would eliminate this possibility for practical purposes), or the diodes are not the part number you think.

Comment: Fake parts? I measured several BZX83C33 500mW Zeners (rated test current 5mA) in your circuit and the voltages varied from 4.05 to 4.15 volts.

Comment: The resistor is definitely 22 Ohms (actually 21.7 according to the multi-meter).  I've also tested the voltages on two different multi-meters and an oscilloscope, which all give very similar measurements.  Also, 1N4728A is clearly printed on the diodes.
So I'm left wondering if I have a dodgy batch of components, although @BruceAbbott seems to get a similar result to me with a different part?

Comment: Where did you get them from? Can you show us a photo of one?

Comment: I've added photos of the diode and kit it came in to the original question.  All the diodes I've tested in the kit give pretty consistent results.  The kit was bought off Amazon.

Comment: Do you trust Bojack of  China? Is he a dumpster diver who gets and sells manufacturer's rejects? Buy Name Brand parts instead.

Comment: Did you measure (ideally with a four wire tester) the resistance of your resistor? Typically they can have a 10% tolerance, that and the +- 150 mV tolerance in Zener voltage  could explain this

Answer (score 1):

Behavior found with simulator [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm).
If you measure something as 4 V, then it is not a 1N4728A.

NB: Note that if this diode has been "used" and "mistreated" for some reason, some characteristics have been "changed".

Simulation seems ok, current too.

[image]

Comment: I get the same result in an LT Spice and CircuitLab simulation too.  So, I'm not sure if the components I have are faulty or the simulation model is flawed

Comment: Marking error probably.

Comment: All Name Brand zener diodes I have used are rated at 5mA and had accurate voltages. Low voltage zener diodes have poor voltage regulation then of course the voltage is much higher when the current is massive.